# Getting errors - c programming

Tags: c, error-handling

Getting these errors when I try and running this simple C program code in VB. need help rectifying them.

```
C2371 'CopySubString': redefinition;different basic types
```

Here is the code:

```
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Name: CopySubString
// Abstract: Copy substring from source string to destination string
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
int CopySubString(char strDestination[], char strSource[], int intStartIndex, int intEndIndex)
{
    int intCount = 0;
    int intIndex = 0;

    for (intIndex = intStartIndex; intIndex <= intEndIndex; intIndex += 1)
    {
        strDestination[intCount] = strSource[intIndex];

        intCount = +1;
    }
    
    return strDestination[intCount];
}
```

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with VB.NET.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon.  More urgently, please read about how to create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))
(or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).

Comment: The first problem is in `AppendSourceToDestination()` — you have `int intLength = strDestination;` but `strDestination` is a `char *`.  The second problem is in `printReverse()` — you have `int intIndex = strSource - 1;` which is again assigning a `char *` to an `int`.  In the first case, maybe you need `int intLength = strlen(strDestination);` and in the second maybe you need `int intIndex = 0;`.  The `printReverse()` function doesn't use its `strDestination` parameter.  There isn't an obvious problem with `CopySubString()` which suggests that the code you pasted isn't the code you compiled.

Comment: Please note that your edited code is now sub-minimal; compiling just that code does not reproduce the error.  It must not only be short; it must also be complete enough to show the problem — at least on your system.

Answer (score 0):

I believe below line is problematic:

```
intCount = +1;
```

Change it as below and retry.

```
intCount += 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

The mistake and the correct solution is provided in [@Anjali Agrawal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62888119/11471113)'s answer.

You can enhance the code with  better comprehensibility by:

1. Using simple names for identifiers.
2. Using `,` operator to increment both variables.

---

**The better code:**

```
int copySubString(char strDest[], char strSrc[], int start, int end) {
    int count = 0;

    for (int index = start; index < end; index++, count++)
        strDest[count] = strSrc[index];
    
    return strDest[count];
}
```